# WP Rest API - How to convert embedded to json object in Java

Tags: rest-api, json

I want to get embedded image from WordPress Rest api with my posts. I find out that i should add `_embed` or `_embed=true` as query param with my request. Result have extra `_embedded` part like this:
[image]
I put embeddedDto with name _embedded in main json file and create other needed Dtos to handle this.

It seems had problem with highlighted point in image **wp:featuremedia**, how i should parse it to json? I create a class wp that have featuremedia dto. Am i right or not? you can see other Dtos here:

```
public class EmbeddedDto implements Serializable{

    private WPDto wp;

    public WPDto getWp() {
        return wp;
    }

    public void setWp(WPDto wp) {
        this.wp = wp;
    }

}
```

and this:

```
public class WPDto implements Serializable {

    private List<MediaDto> featuremedia;

    public List<MediaDto> getFeaturemedia() {
        return featuremedia;
    }

    public void setFeaturemedia(List<MediaDto> featuremedia) {
        this.featuremedia = featuremedia;
    }

}
```

and finally:

```
public class MediaDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String date;
    private String slug;
    private String link;
    private String title;
    private String source_url;
}
```

But **wp** is always null.

Comment: it is probably not realistic to expect anyone here to have java knowledge, but the error seems to be obvious, you expect tile to be a string while it is an object

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. REST API responses are already in json format. The error says it is expected a string instead of an object, so may you just need to use `$[0]._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].title.rendered` (a string) instead of  `$[0]._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].title` (an object).

Comment: Ok i will update the question

Comment: dear @MarkKaplun  I think I find the answer and it was java trick to handle and pars some json like that, but do not know to answer my question so may it will use-full for some other people or just delete the question? what do you suggest?

Comment: Answer it, it could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with parsing **wp:featuremedia:**. I handle this with `@SerializedName`. Instead of creating class **wp** that contains **featuremedia**,named all to **wp:featuredmedia**

```
public class EmbeddedDto implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia")
    @Expose
    private List<MediaDto> featuremedia;
}
```

Now Json parses in right way.